# Insert query for linked tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Why does my insert query insert 9 records when I just have 3 records?

Here is my table structure:

SubjectTable

```
SubjectID   (Autonumber)    Primary Key
MasterID    (Number)        Foreign Key
Description (Text)
```

MasterTable

```
MasterID    (Autonumber)    Primary Key
StatusID    (Number)        Foreign Key
StudentID   (Text) 
Description (Text)
```

StatusTable

```
StatusID    (Autonumber)    Primary Key
Description (Text)
```

Table Relationships:

```
MasterTable (One) --> (Many) SubjectTable
StatusTable (One) --> (Many) MasterTable
```

Data from Table1 to be inserted in MasterTable:

```
StudentID Description
JP121     Description 1
SP223     Description 2
JK111     Description 3
```

Insert Query:

```
INSERT INTO Master ( StudentID )
SELECT Table1.StudentID
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Just to verify, what you've shown above is the entire contents of `Table1`, and the table `MasterTable` is empty before you run the query?

Comment: No, MasterTable already has data. All tables already have data in them. I am trying to do a data dump using insert query

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise Yes, I am testing this with a smaller data set before doing it on a larger one. Table1 has more Columns, but I am just inserting StudentID to test.

Comment: Just out of interest, what are the 9 records that get added?  What does `MasterTable` look like after the insert?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise All three StudentID's get added 3 times each:
JP121;
JP121;
JP121;
SP223;
SP223;
SP223;
JK111;
JK111;
JK111;

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise Could it be because these are linked tables with 1 to many and many to one relationships?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise MasterTable displays the 9 inserted StudentID's (3 of each) and other columns are blank, as I am not inserting anything in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the INSERT query programmatically? Perhaps its being executed multiple times.

EDIT: Just a silly query issue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you inserting into the MasterTable without providing a StatusID (given that its a foreign key)? Perhaps there is some sort of built-in trigger that inserts the data once for each StatusID.

Comment: It doesnt show any error, I will try to insert it with StatusID and see if it still inserts multiple times.

Comment: Even after providing StatusID, it inserts same record multiple times.

Comment: Hmm...would it be practical for you to wipe all the data and try running the query on an empty DB?

Comment: Yes, just tried that. Now it doesnt insert any records. It says you are about to append 0 row(s). Even after having data in source table.

Comment: I have a test access db with tables, relationships and insert query setup, I can email it to you if you want to look at it?

Comment: What email should I send at?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25743/discussion-between-crazylpfan-and-user793468)